# GET and display member status (or error) with Mailchimp API 3.0

Tags: javascript, php, curl, mailchimp

Creating a Mailchimp signup form.

Would like to first check member status, then add or update as needed.

First step is opening a connection with the Mailchimp 3.0 API, get member status and display the status or error.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML for form:

```
        <!--Newsletter-->
    <section title="Newsletter" id="newsletter" class="basicbox">
        <h2>Sign Up for the Newsletter</h2>
        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
        <div id="newsletter-form">
            <form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" method="post" action="#" target="_blank">
                <fieldset id="mc_embed_signup">
                    <p><input type="text" name="fname" class="required" placeholder="First name" title="It would be great to know your name."></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="lname" class="required" placeholder="Last name" title="It would be great to know your last name."></p>
                    <p><input type="email" name="email" class="required email" placeholder="Your email address" title="Hey, I need your email address so I know where to send the newsletter." ></p>

                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                    <p><small>I respect your privacy and will not share your contact information.</small></p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

JS for form (at bottom of the same HTML doc, before the closing `</body` tag:

```
<!-- Begin JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.32/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!--  validate newsletter form-->
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').validate({
      rules: {
                fname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                lname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
      },
      messages: {
                fname: {
                    required: "Oh come on, I really need to know your name.",
                    minlength: "Surely your name is longer than one character."
                },
                lname: {
                    required: "I'm normally not formal, but what is your surname?",
                    minlength: "Surely your name is longer than one character."
                },
        email: {
          required: "Hey, I need your email address so I know where to send the newsletter."
        },
      },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
          $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            url: 'process_mc_status.php',
            success: function() {
                $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').hide();
                $('#newsletter-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Working on adding your awesome self to the list.</p>")
              }
            });
          }
        });

                // How to now display the status?
                // $('#newsletter-form').append("<p class='thanks'>"), $user_status, "</p>"
```

And here is the PHP, in process_mc_status.php:

```
<?php

// Let's track errors in a log //
    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'errorlog.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

  // Your Mailchimp account info //

    // Data Center
    $datacent = '{dataCenter}';

    // List ID
    $listid = '{listID}';

    // API key
    $mc_apikey = '{APIKey}';


  // Email cleamup and member ID (leid) //

    // Grab email address
    $email = "strip_tags($_POST['email'])";

      // Make email all lowercase
      $email = strtolower($email);

      // member ID, is email covert to md5
      $leid = md5($email);


    // first and last name variables //
      // $fname = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
      // $lname = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);

      $json_data = "";

  // MailChimp API 3.0 URL for member status //

    //  /3.0/lists/{$listid}/members/{$leid}
    $mc_url = "https://" . $datacent . ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" . $listid . "/members/" . $leid;




  // Get status from Mailchimp //


    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Let's track errors in a log //
        $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'errorlog.txt', 'w');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

    // Gete connection going //
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mc_url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$mc_apikey));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

      // $json_data contains the output string
        // this method
        // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_GET,count($fields));
       //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS, $json_data);
          // OR
        // this method
        $json_data = curl_exec($ch);

      // Check for errors
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      $errno = curl_errno($ch);
      if( $json_data === false || $errno != 0 ) {
          // Do error checking
      } else if($info['http_code'] != 200) {
          // Got a non-200 error code.
          // Do more error checking
      }

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

  // Get status from JSON //
    $user_status = var_dump(json_decode($json_data->status));

    echo $json_data;
    echo "<br><br><br>";
    echo 'User status is: '.$user_status;


?>
```

The above hits the mailchimp server, it dumps all of the user data to the page, but the value of status is NULL. How do you extract just the status from the member information? Also tried `$user_status = $json_data['status'];` with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the `$user_status` variable with a string value of `'status'`. Independent of what the json data is, it will always echo `'status'`.

Try this instead:

```
// Get status from JSON //
json_decode($json_data, true);
$user_status = $json_data['status'];
```

Then just print it anyway you want to show on screen:

```
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo 'User status is: '.$user_status;
```

Comment: Realized "status" was loading as a string and made a few attempts to correct, including:

`$user_status = var_dump(json_decode($json_data->status));`

Also tried you suggestion, in both cases I got the following:


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object... 
NULL

Comment: Got it to work with:
 `// Get status from JSON //
    $json_data = json_decode(utf8_encode($json_data));
    $user_status = $json_data->status;

     echo 'User status is: '.$user_status;`

Comment: That's right. `json_decode` will only return an array if a second argument is provided, otherwise it will return an object. I'm editing the response. Glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with:
 `// Get status from JSON //
    $json_data = json_decode(utf8_encode($json_data));
    $user_status = $json_data->status;

```
 echo 'User status is: '.$user_status;`
```